Does the quotient set uniquely determine arbitrary homogenous relations?
It seems totally reasonable to me to generalize the quotient of equivalence relations to general ones:

Given a binary relation $R$ over sets $X, Y$, each $x \in X$ has an $R$-class, denoted $[x]_R = \{y \in Y : yRx\}$. The quotient of $X$ with respect to $R$ is $X/R = \{[x]_R : x \in X\}$, a subset of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$.

I am wondering if the following result is preserved.

Let $R, S$ be equivalence relations over a set $X$. If $X/R = X/S$, then $R = S$.
Proof. We will show that $R \subseteq S$, and the converse would follow, mutatis mutandis. Let $(x, y) \in R$. Since $X/R = X/S$, there exist an $y' \in X$ such that $[y']_S = [y]_R$. Since $x \in [y]_R$, $xSy'$. It follows from reflexivity and symmetry that $y \in [y']_S \implies ySy' \implies y'Sy$. Lastly, by transitivity, $xSy \implies (x, y) \in S$, as required.

My intuition is no, but somehow I can't find an easy counterexample.

Take $X=\{1,2\}$, $R=\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$ and $S=\{(1,2),(2,2)\}$. Then, $$X/R=\{[1]_R,[2]_R\}=\{\{1,2\},\emptyset\}$$
and
$$X/S=\{[1]_S,[2]_S\}=\{\{1,2\},\emptyset\}$$
Hope this helps. :)

right... my brain is not working today. But do you have any idea as to the necessary conditions on the relation for the theorem to hold?

Actually $X/R = {[1]_R, [2]_R} = {{1,2},\emptyset}$
